# React Warning: Function components cannot be given refs

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have a Component that renders a Material UI MenuItem with icon and text:

```
export default class ProjectMenuItem extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MenuItem onClick={this.props.onClick}>
        <ListItemIcon>{this.props.iconComponent}</ListItemIcon>
        <ListItemText primary={this.props.text} />
      </MenuItem>
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine.
What I am struggling to understand is why I get a **Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.** *if I change this component to a functional component* :

```
export const ProjectMenuItem = ({ onClick, iconComponent, text }) => {
  return (
    <MenuItem onClick={onClick}>
      <ListItemIcon>{iconComponent}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </MenuItem>
  );
};
```

The parent component:

```
      <StyledMenu
        id='customized-menu'
        anchorEl={anchorEl}
        keepMounted
        open={Boolean(anchorEl)}
        onClose={handleClose}>
        {projectMenuItens.map((menuItem, i) => (
          <ProjectMenuItem
            key={i}
            onClick={menuItem.onClick}
            text={menuItem.text}
            iconComponent={menuItem.iconComponent}
          />
        ))}
      </StyledMenu>
```

The full warning is:

> Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access
> this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()? Check the render method of `ForwardRef(Menu)`.

Comment: check this https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/issues/15903#issuecomment-496313450. It might solve your problem.

Comment: You can also check the official [MUI docs](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/composition/#caveat-with-refs) for handling `ref` with their components.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The `StyledMenu` component tries to assign a ref to your `ProjectMenuItem` components. Refs cannot be used on function components because they don't have instances. You may only use them on class components or DOM elements.

If you want `ProjectMenuItem` to be a function component, use react's `React.forwardRef` utility:

```js
export const ProjectMenuItem = React.forwardRef(({onClick, iconComponent, text}, ref) => (
    <MenuItem onClick={onClick} ref={ref}>
      <ListItemIcon>{iconComponent}</ListItemIcon>
      <ListItemText primary={text} />
    </MenuItem>
));
```

You can read more on refs in [the official react docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html).

Comment: Will it cause problems to ignore this error, if everything works as expected ? (might be related: [react-router, forwardRef API in withRouter](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/6056#issuecomment-435524678))

Comment: @kca The above message says "Warning" but not "Error" and is generated by React itself, so concerning React you won't get any runtime errors if you ignore this warning.
However, other components which use the affected functional component as a child might rely on it accepting a ref, so make sure to read the docs and to examine the source code.

Comment: This does not explain why that error is given for a class component.