# Why does custom input component cause "Function components cannot be given refs" warning?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui

While trying to customize the `input` component via [MUI's `InputUnstyled` component](https://mui.com/base/react-input/) (or any other unstyled component, e.g. `SwitchUnstyled`, `SelectUnstyled` etc.), I get the warning

```
Warning: Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail. Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

Check the render method of `ForwardRef`.
InputElement@http://localhost:3000/main.4c2d885b9953394bb5ec.hot-update.js:59:45
div
...
```

I use the `components` prop to define a custom `Input` element in my own `MyStyledInput` component which wraps MUIs `InputUnstyled`:

```
import InputUnstyled, {
    InputUnstyledProps
} from '@mui/base/InputUnstyled';

const MyStyledInput: React.FC<InputUnstyledProps> = props => {
    const { components, ...otherProps } = props;

    return (
        <InputUnstyled
            components={{
                Input: InputElement,
                ...components,
            }}
            {...otherProps}
        />
    );
};
```

My custom `input` component `InputElement` which is causing the `Function components cannot be given refs` warning:

```
import {
    InputUnstyledInputSlotProps,
} from '@mui/base/InputUnstyled';
import { Box, BoxProps } from '@mui/material';

const InputElement: React.FC<BoxProps & InputUnstyledInputSlotProps> = (
    { ownerState, ...props }
) => {
    return (
        <Box
            component="input"
            // any style customizations
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
        />
    );
});
```

**Note**: I'm using `component="input` to make MUI's `Box` component not render an HTML `div` but an HTML `input` component in the DOM.

**Why** am I getting this warning?

Other related questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62645556/3210677), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56484686/3210677) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61450739/3210677) address similar issues but don't work with MUI Unstyled components. These threads also don't explain **why**

Answer (score 1):

The warning wants you to have a look at the `InputElement` component. To be honest, the stack-trace is a bit misleading here. It says:

> Check the render method of `ForwardRef`.
> InputElement@http://localhost:3000/main.4c2d885b9953394bb5ec.hot-update.js:59:45
> div

You can ignore the `ForwardRef` here. Internally `InputElement` is wrapped by

The crucial part for understanding this warning is:

> Function components cannot be given refs. Attempts to access this ref will fail.

That is, if someone tries to access the actual HTML `input` element in the DOM via a `ref` (which Material UI actually tries to do), it will not succeed because the functional component `InputElement` is not able to pass that `ref` on to the `input` element (here created via a MUI `Box` component).

Hence, the warning continues with:

> Did you mean to use React.forwardRef()?

This proposes the solution to wrap your function component with `React.forwardRef`. `forwardRef` gives you the possibility to get hold of the `ref` and pass it on to the actual `input` component (which in this case is the `Box` component with the prop `component="input"`). It should look as such:

```
import {
    InputUnstyledInputSlotProps,
} from '@mui/base/InputUnstyled';
import { Box, BoxProps } from '@mui/material';

const InputElement = React.forwardRef<
    HTMLInputElement,
    BoxProps & InputUnstyledInputSlotProps
>(({ ownerState, ...props }, ref) => {
    const theme = useTheme();

    return (
        <Box
            component="input"
            // any style customizations
            {...props}
            ref={ref}
        />
    );
});
```

---

**Why do I have to deal with the `ref` in the first place?**

In case of an HTML `input` element, there as a high probability you want to access it's DOM node via a `ref`. This is the case if you use your React `input` component as an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html). An uncontrolled input component holds its state (i.e. whatever the user enters in that input field) in the actual DOM node and not inside of the state value of a `React.useState` hook. If you control the input value via a `React.useState` hook, you're using the input as a [controlled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components).

**Note**: An input with `type="file"` is always an uncontrolled component. This is explained in the [React docs section about the file input tag](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html#the-file-input-tag).